# Simple AlphaNumeric Regex (single spacing) without Catastrophic Backtracking

Tags: regex, backtracking

I have the following REGEX expression (that works) to allow Alpha-Numeric (as well as `'` and `-`) and no double spacing:

```
  ^([a-zA-Z0-9'-]+\s?)*$
```

Due to the nested grouping, this allows Catastrophic Backtracking to happen - which is bad!

**How can I simplify this expression to avoid Catastrophic Backtracking??** 
(Ideally this wouldn't allow white-space in first and last characters either)

Comment: Thank you. Ended up using ^[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+(\s[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+)*$

Comment: To get the full throw, you could allow whitespace on the boundary's without allowing double's `^\s?[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+(\s[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+)*\s?$` Whats real odd is that `\s` can be a CR or LF, but only one is allowed. Text with `"asdfas\r\nabafbgb"` would not be cached.

Comment: To avoid the `\s` and line-break problem all together, you could use the `\h` horizontal whitespace construct instead, or `[^\S\r\n]`. Or if you would allow a single line-break `(?:[^\S\r\n]|\r?\n)`

Comment: Thank you for your help. All I really needed was to allow single spacing (no other like-breaks etc). Do you know of a way to avoid allowing Spaces at the first and last character? Struts validation seems to pass these spaces, though regex101.com tester behaves as I'd like however

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation

Nested group doesn't automatically causes catastrophic backtracking. In your case, it is because your regex degenerates to the classical example of catastrophic backtracking `(a*)*`.

Since `\s` in optional in `^([a-zA-Z0-9'-]+\s?)*$`, on input without any spaces but has characters outside the allowed list, the regex simply degenerates to `^([a-zA-Z0-9'-]+)*$`.

You can also think in term of expansion of the original regex:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+\s?[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+\s?[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+\s?[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+\s?...
```

Since `\s` is optional, we can remove it:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+...
```

And we got a series of consecutive `[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+`, which will try all ways to distribute the characters between themselves and blow up the complexity.

### Solution

The standard way to write a regex to match `token delimiter token ... delimiter token` is `token (delimiter token)*`. While it is possible to rewrite the regex avoid repeating `token`, I'd recommend against it, since it is harder to get it right. To avoid repetition , you might want to construct the regex by string concatenation instead.

Following the recipe above:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+(\s[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+)*$
```

Although you can see repetition in repetition here, there is no catastrophic backtracking, since the regex can only expand to:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+\s[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+\s[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+\s[a-zA-Z0-9'-]+...
```

And `\s` and `[a-zA-Z0-9'-]` are mutual exclusive - there is only one way to match any string.

Comment: Thank you. It works well! Not sure why Struts 2 seems to allow spacing at the beginning and at the end even with this REGEX