# RegExp freezes on execution in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm having a really weird issue where a RegExp freezes when executing (or testing) on a particular string. This is my RegExp:

```
/when( .+)* enters the battlefield/gim
```

And this is the particular text that causes the freezing

```
"Lifelink\nWhen Queen's Agent enters the battlefield, it explores. (Reveal the top card of your library. Put that card into your hand if it's a land. Otherwise, put a +1/+1 counter on this creature, then put the card back or put it into your graveyard.)",
```

It freezes both on Chrome and on Nodejs (v9.6.1). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [Remove `*` quantifier.](https://regex101.com/r/q6XNGH/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks! That solved it, why though ? `enters the battlefield` was being put into the group ?

Comment: Read [nhahtdh's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27240937/3832970). It is similar here. A quantified group where neighboring (or adjoining) subpatterns can match the same symbols in the middle of the pattern always behave like this.

Comment: If you are the curious kind of person [here is a good read on the subject](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html)